# Magento 1 :How can I set Any Kind of Discount is not apply for Specified Product?

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

I have Five Prime Products in Magento 1 site And I want to set Condition for that

> No any Kind of Discount apply on this particular Product.

Problem is Discount Coupon is Apply on this product and I not wont to apply.

How can i set Condition 
**If cart contains Prime Product then coupon code should be invalid.**

Answer (score 1):

Here is the process to create **Coupon Code** for any particular product:-

> - Login to Admin
> - Go to **Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules**
> - Click Add New Rule
> - Fill Rule Information

**Set Conditions**

> - On left sidebar, click **Conditions** tab
> - Click + button icon
> - Select **Product attribute combination**
> - Click + button icon
> - Select **SKU**
> - Now, you will see **SKU is ...**
> - Put your product SKU over there

***Please note*** that the SKU option may not show up by default. (*Go to: catalog -> attributes -> manage attributes. Then search for the ‘SKU’ attribute and set the drop down ‘Use for Promo Rule Conditions’ to YES and reindex if needed.)*

**Set Actions**

> - You can set how much discount you want to give from here
> - **Save Rule**

Comment: i know how to set price rule but it was not work and discount is applied on cart when i will use discount coupon  code on cart.

Comment: if you have another solution for this then provide me ok...

Comment: follow all step mention in my answer ???

Comment: i have list of other cart price rules so i need to modify other rules or not for this condition ?

Comment: no....you just create a rule for prime product